# Mandrill: How long do I wait before assuming deliverability?

Tags: email, mandrill

I've set up a Mandrill webhook which will update my app whenever an email hard-bounces or is rejected, so I don't keep that particular email address in my database. The way it works is this: a user gives me an address, I send him a confirmation, and if I don't hear from Mandrill's webhook in 30 minutes, I assume it's OK.

So I ran a some tests with non-existing addresses, and they didn't go too well. Most of them appeared as delivered for hours, long after I'd assumed they were fine.

Also, I didn't account for the delay in receiving webhook batches. One mail bounced at 2:01pm, according to the outbound activity logs, but the webhook history shows a batch being sent only at 2:52pm.

My questions is: how long should I delay my app's assumption of deliverability in order to give Mandrill enough time to detect hard-bounces / rejections and then send me webhook batches? I can live with letting some 5% bad emails going by because of delayed in processing on peak-time or other extraordinary events, but it seems like my 30 minutes isn't enough to catch anything at all...

Comment: Any luck here? I'm trying the same thing...

Comment: Sorry to say, but I found no way out with Mandrill by itself. Some messages to fake Gmail accounts would stay "delivered" for days. It could be a Gmail-specific problem, but I couldn't code my way around it. I ended up using a paid email verifier API which gave me immediate response whether the account existed or not. A terrible solution, but it seemed to get the job done at the time.

Comment: Be aware that mandrill often blocks the emails in a 'secret' queue and never delivers them even if they are reported as "Sent" by the API and "delivered" in the mandrill UI. I've just found this 1 day ago so I thought you may want to know it.

Comment: @tbuteler would you mind saying what service you used and if it works well?  Also, it seems that if you look at the message from the mandrill events or frmo the API to check for the smtp_events and find a 250 or similar in there, its safe to assume it was delivered... anything short of that doesnt indicate delivery...  Unfortunately there doesnt appear to be an even generated when this happens... so their "sent" means nothing really... and its about impossible to talk to anyone there, even by email so i'm a bit skeptical...

Comment: We used a paid service from the guys at http://my-addr.com/, I think. It was very cheap, but also incredibly slow, so I only called their API via queue. I cannot endorse it at all, though, since it's still a mystery to me how such a service can exist: I've read everywhere that no mail service would reliably or truthfully reveal which accounts exist or not, which is why I wanted to implement a solution based on real deliverability. Anyway, my guess is Mandrill doesn't want us to know this, and it must be related to spam.

Comment: @tbutler I'm interested in what you finally used, but we had relative success with both mailgun and sendgrid in this respect... mandrill seems to have other advantages, but the fact that their "sent" event doesnt mean "delivered", and they dont have a spearate "delivered" event makes it kinda useless.... We cant poll mandrill API for each and ALL email sends for upto 72hs to see if we get SMTP 250...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the answer you're looking for, but Mandrill doesn't let you do this.  The only way of checking if an email has been delivered is to poll Mandrill (with the [message/info.json API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html#method=info)). To see if the message is delivered you have to check the `smtp_events` and look for an event with `diag` starting with 250. As you've already experienced it may take a long time between delivery and when a message is accessible through the API. In my experience the normal case is around 10 minutes, but it might take many, many hours (this is the case for bounced emails as well as emails that got delivered immediately).

If it is important to you to know when an email is delivered, I would recommend you to switch to another email provider. [There](https://sendgrid.com/) [are](https://www.mailgun.com/) [plenty](https://www.mailjet.com/) [of](https://postmarkapp.com/) [different](http://www.socketlabs.com/) [ones](https://www.smtp.com/) out there. I've personally used [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/). They're cheaper than Mandrill, and you can expect a delivery notification after a second or so. Do note that Amazon SES is a bit more bare-bone than Mandrill (they don't have support for open/click-tracking, templating, dedicated IP, etc.), so it might not be the right provider for you.

Comment: Finally, a more definitive answer, though I had given up on it long ago.